# How can I test if my custom USB HID controller works in ps4 without a console?

Tags: usb, hid, playstation, ps4

I'm designing my own PS4 controller based on a pic microcontroller but my console is currently broken so I can't test if it works. Is it possible to test (on PC) whether it'll work on PS4 or not?

Maybe theres some obscure software out there that can help me with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Despite the fact that DualShock4 is almost usual HID gamepad - you cannot just do clone that would work with PS4. PS4 controllers are using special authentication sequence that you cannot fake without knowing of Sony crypto private key.
See https://www.psdevwiki.com/ps4/DS4-BT for some hight level protocol details (especially 0xF1/0xF20/0xF0 HID reports).